# Batch for getting MAC address and creating file named as where MAC found

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file

I want to make a batch script for purpose of showing status of re-imaging workstation at every part of progress. I have a batch file for getting GHO file from a Samba folder, and I want to expand it to show the reimaining progress by creating a `.txt` file on the Samba share.

My idea is when the process starts, the batch file needs to lookup the MAC address, either in a CSV file or in a group of files like `wks1.conf` and `wks2.conf`. Inside there is information about MAC address and IP address, delimited with comma.

When MAC address is found, I want to create a `.txt` file named a workstation name (like `wks1.txt`) with some text (hey, I am that and that machine and my IP address should be that and that)...

I already found a few parts of the batch file to find a MAC address, but I don't know how to lookup the IP address in a CSV file.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions

rem call :GetIP ip_WLAN "Drahtlos"
rem echo ---
set OS_Version=XP
call :GetIP result  "Ethernet adapter" "Physical"

echo mac=%result%

goto :next

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:GetIP <resultVar> <AdapterName>
:: resultVar    return variable for the searched value
:: AdapterName  part of the adapter name
setlocal
set /a found=0
if "%OS_Version%"=="Win7" set ipText=IPv4
if "%OS_Version%"=="Vista" set ipText=IPv4
if "%OS_Version%"=="XP" set ipText=IP-
if "%~3"=="" (
    set searchText=!ipText!
) ELSE (
    set "searchText=%~3"
)
for /F "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a IN ('ipconfig /all') DO (  
  call :Normalize first "%%a.dummy"
  call :Normalize post "%%b.dummy"

  if "!post!"=="_" (
    if "!first:%~2=!" NEQ "!first!" (
        set /a found=1
        rem echo adapter found "!first!"
    ) ELSE (
        if "!first!" NEQ "_" (
            set /a found=0
            rem echo - !first! !post!
        )
    )
  )

  if !found! EQU 1 (
    rem echo try "!first!"
    if "!first:%searchText%=!" NEQ "!first!" (
        set ipAddr=!post:_=!
        set ipAddr=!ipAddr: =!
        rem echo IP found !post! for adapter
    )
  )
)

(
  endlocal
  set %~1=%ipAddr%
  goto :eof
)

:Normalize
set %~1=_%~n2
goto :eof

:next
set mac=%result%
echo %mac%


for /f "delims=" %%b in ('findstr /i %MAC% "\\10.51.10.10\DDC-    Configuration\*"') do set file=%%b
echo Hey, I am WKS with name %XXX% and I should have this IP %YYY% >         %file%
```

There are some solutions with `getmac` command, but I don't know if it avaiable in `WinRE.wim` (a.k.a. "Repair My Computer") environment where I want to do the re-imaging.

Comment: maybe "wmic nic get MACAddress" could help here

Comment: Thanx but WinRE.wim is higly small size Windows. I customized it to use my batch to pull image from samba server and it is working.

Comment: There is this batch for getting MAC...
    
    for /f "tokens=3 delims=," %%a in ('"getmac /v /fo csv | findstr Ethernet"') do set MAC=%%a
    echo MAC address of this computer is %MAC%

But MAC is always under " sings...

Comment: Hello All!

I create this batch and so far it is functionating as I want it.

    @echo off

    for /f "tokens=3 delims=," %%a in ('"getmac /v /fo csv | findstr     Ethernet"') do set MAC=%%a
    echo MAC address of this computer is %MAC%

    for /f "delims=" %%c in ('findstr /I %MAC% "\\10.51.10.10\DDC-Configuration\*"') do set "var=%%~nc"
    set "var=%var:~0,-1%"
    echo "%var%"

    echo hey I am %var%


    echo Re-imageing is started at DDC with MAC address: %MAC% at time: %time% > %var%.txt

If anybody knwos a better way to accomplish this, please explain.

BRGD.

Comment: I have a problem with loop